# Add alternative email address for recovery option

Tags: support, user-accounts, email

I am running my account with stack-exchange login. For recovery and security account has one email id by using which I logged in.

Now, can I register second email id to same account **as a secondary or alternative email id** by which I will recover my account if required in feauture? (Though I can successfully login with my 1st-primary email id)

Then how to add secondary email id to my account? or It is not permitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [add other OpenID logins](https://askubuntu.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=/users/current). This relies on you having another account elsewhere but any of them will log you into SE globally.

I realise that isn't the same thing as what you're asking but has the same effect.

Comment: Just to note, there is a problem with [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=/users/current), as it won't allow you to add more logins. It is only working on [main](http://askubuntu.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=/users/current). Trying to see if the bug is already reported.

Comment: @Dan I don't think it's a bug. Meta doesn't have all the features main does.